# Cancelling an order in WooCommerce after a time period

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have online store in WooCommerce and there is an option that is: if x time duration reached then change the status of that order to canceled and also set the stock where it was before order submitted.

I want to change it if x time duration reached then order status change to complete and also item was reduce from the stock.

as far as I know that is the code of reduce stock and cancel the order.

```
/**
 * woocommerce_cancel_unpaid_orders function.
 *
 * @access public
 * @return void
 */
function woocommerce_cancel_unpaid_orders() {
    global $wpdb;

    $held_duration = get_option( 'woocommerce_hold_stock_minutes' );

    if ( $held_duration < 1 || get_option( 'woocommerce_manage_stock' ) != 'yes' )
        return;

    $date = date( "Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime( '-' . absint( $held_duration ) . ' MINUTES', current_time( 'timestamp' ) ) );

    $unpaid_orders = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "
        SELECT posts.ID
        FROM {$wpdb->posts} AS posts
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} AS rel ON posts.ID=rel.object_ID
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} AS tax USING( term_taxonomy_id )
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->terms} AS term USING( term_id )

        WHERE   posts.post_type   = 'shop_order'
        AND     posts.post_status = 'publish'
        AND     tax.taxonomy      = 'shop_order_status'
        AND     term.slug         IN ('pending')
        AND     posts.post_modified < %s
    ", $date ) );

    if ( $unpaid_orders ) {
        foreach ( $unpaid_orders as $unpaid_order ) {
            $order = new WC_Order( $unpaid_order );

            if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cancel_unpaid_order', true, $order ) )
                $order->update_status( 'cancelled', __( 'Unpaid order cancelled - time limit reached.', 'woocommerce' ) );
        }
    }

    wp_clear_scheduled_hook( 'woocommerce_cancel_unpaid_orders' );
    wp_schedule_single_event( time() + ( absint( $held_duration ) * 60 ), 'woocommerce_cancel_unpaid_orders' );
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_cancel_unpaid_orders', 'woocommerce_cancel_unpaid_orders' );
```

Personally I did this changes, do they make sense?

```
/**
 * woocommerce_cancel_unpaid_orders function.
 *
 * @access public
 * @return void
 */
function woocommerce_cancel_unpaid_orders() {
    global $wpdb;

    $held_duration = get_option( 'woocommerce_hold_stock_minutes' );

    if ( $held_duration < 1 || get_option( 'woocommerce_manage_stock' ) != 'yes' )
        return;

    $date = date( "Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime( '-' . absint( $held_duration ) . ' MINUTES', current_time( 'timestamp' ) ) );

    $unpaid_orders = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "
        SELECT posts.ID
        FROM {$wpdb->posts} AS posts
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} AS rel ON posts.ID=rel.object_ID
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} AS tax USING( term_taxonomy_id )
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->terms} AS term USING( term_id )

        WHERE   posts.post_type   = 'shop_order'
        AND     posts.post_status = 'publish'
        AND     tax.taxonomy      = 'shop_order_status'
        AND     term.slug         IN ('pending')
        AND     posts.post_modified < %s
    ", $date ) );

    if ( $unpaid_orders ) {
        foreach ( $unpaid_orders as $unpaid_order ) {
            $order = new WC_Order( $unpaid_order );

            if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_payment_complete_order_status', true, $order ) )
                $order->update_status( 'completed', __( 'order completed - time limit reached.', 'woocommerce' ) );
        }
    }

    wp_clear_scheduled_hook( 'woocommerce_payment_complete_order_status' );
    wp_schedule_single_event( time() + ( absint( $held_duration ) * 60 ), 'woocommerce_payment_complete_order_status' );
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete_order_status', 'woocommerce_payment_complete_order_status' );
```

I was replace this filter 'woocommerce_cancel_unpaid_order' with this woocommerce_payment_complete_order_status

and chnaged this
$order->update_status( 'cancelled', __( 'Unpaid order cancelled - time limit reached.', 'woocommerce' ) );

with this one

$order->update_status( 'completed', __( 'order completed - time limit reached.', 'woocommerce' ) );

not tested till yet bcz i want confirmation before testing it.

Comment: Can you highlight your modifications? And explain the results you expect and the result you get?

Comment: Please review i have updated

Comment: Did you find an answer for this?